# System building: two Asrock boards in a row with defective RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building, defective-hardware

I am still working on my new build 8700k with an ASRock Fatal1ty Z370 Gaming K6. [The full story is documented here](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/7xcx5m/post_issues_with_new_build_asrock_z370/%5D) a long with a complete parts list but there's not much more to it other than "won't post, suspect faulty board".

This board seems to have the same problem as the first one which I already RMA'd: it won't boot, post code "40" which corresponds to "unspecified RAM error". I've tried with two different sticks, and then I bought another 16GB and tried each one. Nothing: just "Error 40". The new RAM is a 2x 8GB DDR4 3466 which I got directly from Crucial and didn't shop around, so as to use their system/parts finder utility. And this time there's no doubt about the read out: it's definitely error code 40, no matter which slot I put the RAM stick in.

At this point it seems pretty unlikely to me that two boards in a row would be RAM-defective, or four RAM sticks. What am I doing wrong?

[Here are photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDWU0.jpg)

Comment: If you want help we need exact part numbers

Comment: Verify the memory is on the [QVL](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Fatal1ty%20Z370%20Professional%20Gaming%20i7/index.asp#Memory)

Comment: @Ramhound: check the link in the question for a full parts list :-)

Comment: Relevant information should be contained in the question body.

Comment: @Ramhound: it is.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have Corsair CMR16GX4M2C3600C18, but the QVL only lists CMR16GX4M2F4000C19. The other kit I have, "Ballistix by Micron", isn't listed on the QVL but was purchased from Crucial using their system parts checker utility (I entered the exact model of my MB). Do you reckon the problem is that the RAM isn't compatible then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the mainboard BIOS readout indicating a RAM error, it turned out to be the only component I didn't have the opportunity to test: the CPU. Obvious process of elimination really...